# Visual Studio 2012: Check in to tfs with the command window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

Is it possible to check in project to tfs via the command window? (not developer command propmt)

Or to some way integrate the developer command prompt into vs 2012 like the command window?
The command window is under View -> Other Windows -> Command Window

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you  to run `TFS power tools` (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f/), you execute `Tf Check In` command

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c327ca1z(v=vs.100).aspx

You can also create console application(.exe), based on `c# API TFS`, and run .exe.

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.checkin.aspx